# Current moment in H2 database

Tags: timestamp, h2, sql-timestamp

How to get the actual current clock time, the current moment, in H2 database?

The [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#current_timestamp) function gives the moment when the current database transaction began. Is there a way to get the current moment, **the time when the current statement is executing**? This may be the same or later than `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

For comparison, in [Postgres](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPostgreSQL), some functions such as `current_timestamp` return the transaction start time while some functions such as [`clock_timestamp`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) return the actual current clock time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Current time (of function call)

You could create an [`ALIAS`](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html?highlight=alias&search=alias#create_alias) for `System.currentTimeMillis()`:

```sql
CREATE ALIAS CURRENT_TIME_MILLIS FOR "java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis";
```

This wouldn't generate the timestamp of statement execution start, but really the *current* timestamp, whenever H2 actually calls the function - i.e. a non-deterministic moment, and perhaps a different value for different rows within the same statement.

But perhaps, that's good enough for your requirements.

#### Current time (of statement execution)

If the above non-deterministic solution is not sufficiently precise for you, another option would be to implement a JDBC wrapper that intercepts all statements, sets the current time to some thread local (H2 doesn't support `Connection.getClientInfo()`):

```
threadlocal.set(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString());
```

... and then reads that client info from an `ALIAS` like this:

```java
public static Timestamp statementTime() throws SQLException {
    return Timestamp.valueOf(threadlocal.get());
}
```

And then:

```sql
CREATE ALIAS STATEMENT_TIME FOR "com.example.statementTime";
```

Comment: Could you explain in what class this code `threadlocal.set(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString());` must be placed?

Comment: In a JDBC wrapper / proxy that would execute this every time you run something like `Connection.prepareStatement()`. It's up to you.